# In Apache Airflow, can you have a dependency on a previous run of a task?

Tags: python, airflow

Let's say `A_T` means Task A for Today, and `A_T-1` means Task A for Yesterday. Is it possible to specify `A_T-1` as an operator so that I can have a dependency graph like this:

```
A_T   >> B_T
A_T-1 >> B_T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check official documentation about [Cross-DAG Dependencies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html#cross-dag-dependencies). Here's an good practice to follow:

> When two DAGs have dependency relationships, it is worth considering combining them into a single DAG, which is usually simpler to understand. Airflow also offers better visual representation of dependencies for tasks on the same DAG. However, it is sometimes not practical to put all related tasks on the same DAG.

One example of not having all in the same DAG is the following (from the documentation above):

> A task may depend on another task on the same DAG, but for a different `execution_date`.

I think that could be your case, so if you still need that, you can use the [`ExternalTaskSensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html#externaltasksensor) with the argument `execution_delta`. Check [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html#airflow.sensors.external_task.ExternalTaskSensor) for all the details about the parameters of that sensor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of the ExternalTaskSensor, however I don't want a dep on a task from a different DAG. I want the dep on a task from the same DAG, but a previous run of the DAG. Is that also possible with the ExternalTaskSensor?

Comment: Yes, I far as I understand from the docs, you just use the same `dag_id` and `task_id`, and you MUST add the `execution_delta` argument.

Comment: awesome thank you. I'll go read the docs more carefully now. Not knowing whether or not the solution is in the docs makes it harder to digest.

Comment: You're welcome! Normally docs are hard to digest :)